# Fiware: Setting up AuthZForce with idm and pep proxy

Tags: proxy, fiware

I have configured PEP proxy GE and IDM GE, and now Basic authentication works great.
Now i want to set up Level 2:Basic authorization system with http verb and resource path checking, and for that i need AuthZForce GE.
I installed AuthZForce on same server as IDM, created default domain on authZforce with id **562285a1-8950-11e5-980f-6bf3c4dac98a** and configured
pep proxy config.js file

```
config.pep_port = 80;
config.account_host = 'https://192.168.4.180';

config.keystone_host = '192.168.4.180';
config.keystone_port = 5000;

config.app_host = 'localhost';
config.app_port = '8000';

config.azf = {
enabled: true,
host: '192.168.4.180',
port: 8080,
path: '/authzforce/domains/562285a1-8950-11e5-980f-6bf3c4dac98a/pdp'
};
```

And now when i try to access to some page via curl:

```
sudo curl -H "X-Auth-Token: vPTru5ikuyLcxf6ujV23V3l4GFNpF5" http://localhost/home/login/
```

I get this error in the client:

```
Error in AZF communication
```

And this error on pep proxy:

```
2015-11-12 17:09:13.040  - INFO: IDM-Client - Checking token with IDM...
2015-11-12 17:09:13.086  - INFO: AZF-Client - Checking auth with AZF...
2015-11-12 17:09:13.087  - INFO: AZF-Client - Checking authorization to roles [ '4806909eb4b646c7a1f11ad9f9ed53ed',
  '09dc1bdba42c48de9e15e88816284cbc',
  '5786623590bc4f3ab01c61733a13ee6d',
  'e3fe52a0c6c34fe395bb087f42d1cc72',
  '44151592f3814929a59d1c1e7022a0bb' ] to do  GET  on  home/login/
 and app  aea8f4a70b87422cb48068db9f0c6aea
2015-11-12 17:09:13.117  - ERROR: Root - Error in AZF communication  
Error: 139773139036032:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:
unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:795:
```

PEP Proxy is running on port 80
and IDM is running on 443 port.

What could be a problem?
Should all these services be delivered via https or is that irrelevant?

Comment: It seems a problem with the https connection with AZF. Is it listening in https ? You can also try to use http in https://github.com/ging/fiware-pep-proxy/blob/master/lib/azf.js#L144

Comment: Thanks, now it is establishing connection with pep proxy correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the latest version of the PEP proxy, v5.4 as of now, you can work around this issue by disabling https for the connection to AuthzForce in the `config.js` file: you set the `config.azf.protocol` to `http` instead of `https`:

```
config.azf = {
    enabled: true,
    protocol: 'http',
    host: '192.168.4.180',
    port: 8080,
    custom_policy: undefined 
};
```